# What is the best in performance, when select an element (id selector (vs) element+id Selector)

Tags: css, css-selectors

Just I want to know, which one of the following ways that gives a better performance (ie: loading speed), when select an element to apply a style on it

**For example:**

> HTML

```
<div id="box"> content </div>
```

> CSS

```
/* First way */
#box {color:red;}

/* Second way */
div#box {color:red;}
```

Comment: The performance may also vary according to browser implementation. However div#box is a bad practice. You are overqualifying a selector and perf gain or lost will be insignificant

Answer (score 0):

`#box` is faster, cause browser don't need to check if element name equals `div`. But I don't believe that speed difference is noticeable in any natural conditions.

Answer (score 0):

`#box` is better because it uses only one selector (id selector)

`div#box` has two selectors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Answer (score 0):

#box should be faster. But, don't guess it, test it!

http://jsperf.com/id-selector-match

```
div#box
```

is an compound selector. The browser will first match all DIV elements and from that collection will look for an element with the attribute ID = box.

Comment: Actually, browser parse selectors right-to-left, so it'll first select elements with id#box (there may be several, thou should be only one), and then filter them leaving only those with element name equals `div`, as I said in my answer. [proof](http://cssdeck.com/labs/o6fylbly)

Comment: @Paul Kozlovitch: How does that link prove your comment?

Comment: Yes, true. The matching is right-to-left after tokenizing and parsing. Parsing, at least according to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#parsing and what I saw in Chrome code is left-to-right.

Comment: @BoltClock it proves that there can be few elements with equal id and all of them will be selected.

Comment: @PaulKozlovitch: That would be invalid html markup, I believe... (hence why Id's are known to be unique)

Comment: @PaulKozlovitch yeah, I thought so, but you were right with the important matching part.

Comment: @jbutler483 It will for sure, that's why I said that there should be only one, thou most browser wont complain. The point was to show that matching works right-to-left.

Comment: @Paul Kozlovitch: It doesn't prove anything about RTL matching. It simply proves that CSS doesn't assume the document is conforming.

Comment: @PaulKozlovitch: Could you possibly explain how exactly it does that in your sample? I'm of the same opinion as BoltClock here, being that RTL matching isn't being displayed here at all?

Comment: Besides, RTL matching doesn't apply within compound selectors. There is no reason for it to, considering the fact that compound selectors have no notion of order except that type selectors must come first - and those are usually the fastest.

Comment: This snippet shows only that part of my first comment saying that browser will consider all  elements with matching id, thou there should be only one. Can't think of how whole RTL matching process could be shown.

Comment: So your 'proof' was that some browsers allow duplicate id's? Nothing to do with RTL matching?

Comment: Too much drama for a silly question. Bottom line is that the loading perf is insignificant and you should not use IDs for styling pourposes

Comment: @Mircea: That last bit could easily stir up drama of its own ;)

Comment: @BoltClock My bad, didn't know that RTL matching doesn't work for compound selectors, thanks for clarifying.